# is 尿 still pronunced `yao` in 江西话?

Tags: pronunciation, topolect

**《广安方言与民俗词典》** says:

> 【yào】尿“niao4”的音变。此为江西话在广安一些地方的遗存。在实际语言运用中，要注意区分“要来了”与“尿来了”、“我要”与“屙尿”等相似音。
>
> 俗语：“打尿噤”，指因尿急身体突然颤动一两下。
>
> “口水多，无尿屙”，讽刺话语特别多的人。
>
> “你娃儿沟子一翘，老子就晓得你要屙尿”，比喻十分清楚对方的意图。
>
> 歇后语：“鸡公不屙尿——各有各的道”，指公鸡饮水但不排尿，自有它排尿的去处。比喻环境不同，人的际遇也就不同。

Specifically `【yào】尿“niao4”的音变。此为江西话在广安一些地方的遗存。`.

Does this pronunciation still exist in modern-day 江西话?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a zh-Gan native speaker from 吉茶片 永新小片. This prounciation of 尿 still do exist now in my hometown.

Example:'屙尿(ó yào)'

Comment: The excerpt from 《广安方言与民俗词典》 also says:  要注意区分“要来了”与“尿来了”、“我要”与“屙尿”等相似音。do you guys also have the same problem with 我 and 屙？

Comment: @user3306356 Yes, both of them sound quite similar in my hometown(吉安市永新县). But the phrase '我要屙尿/I want to piddle' is hard to be misunderstood because of the slight difference between 我 and 屙 in prounciation. Besides, '要来了' and '尿来了' have the same prounciation.